# Passing ID from php file to another php file

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass my ID from a php file to another php file using $_SESSION but it's not working. It seems that the ID is not being passed. Basically, I use that ID in `dbinsert.php` to know whether to just update or insert the data I have to the database.

**index.php:**

```
    <html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="viewscorescss.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
    <title>Offsourcing Philippines Inc.</title>
    <?php session_start();
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $dbname = "offsourcing";

            $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            // Check connection
            if (!$conn) {
                die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
            }
            if((!empty($_POST['firstname'])) &&
               (!empty($_POST['lastname'])) &&
               (!empty($_POST['middlename']))) {

                   $fname = $_POST['firstname'];
                   $lname = $_POST['lastname'];
                   $mname = $_POST['middlename'];

                   $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM applicants WHERE lastName='$lname' AND fistName='$fname' AND midName='$mname';");
                   $searchid = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
                   $id = $searchid['applicantID'];
                   $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
      } ?>


   <!--NAVIGATION TAB-->
    <div class="row" align="center">
        <img src="images/logo2.png" syle="margin-top:20px">
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="container" id="testTabs">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li class= "active"><a href="#Home" class="btn-sm" role="tab" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#GrammarTab" class="btn-sm" role="tab" style="color: rgb(0, 0,0);">Grammar Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#CustomerServiceTab" class="btn-sm" role="tab" style="color: rgb(0, 0,0);">Customer Service Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#LogicalReasoningTab" class="btn-sm" role="tab" style="color: rgb(0, 0,0);">Logical Reasoning Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#IdiomsTab" class="btn-sm" role="tab" style="color: rgb(0, 0,0);">Idioms Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#CallListeningTab" class="btn-sm" role="tab" style="color: rgb(0, 0,0);">Call Listening Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ViewScoresTab" class="btn-sm" role="tab" style="color: rgb(0, 0,0);">View Scores</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content col-md-10" style="margin-left:105px;  margin-top:10px">
        <div style="background-color: #E9E9E9" class="tab-pane active" id="Home">
            <div class="list-group">
                <div id="fillup" class="col-md-12" >
                    <h4><span class="label label-default">Fill in all fields. </span></h4>
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group" >
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><small>First name:</small></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input type="text" name="firstname" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Firstname" id="firstname" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" align="center" >
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><small> Last name:</small></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input type="text" name="lastname" autocomplete="off" id="lastname" placeholder="Lastname" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" align="center" >
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><small>Middle name:</small></label>
                             <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input type="text" name="middlename" autocomplete="off" id="middlename" placeholder="middlename" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button id="proceedToTest" name="proceedToTest" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Proceed</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div id="tests"  style="display:none">
                   <br>
                    <button style="margin-left:10px; width: 15%" class= "btn btn-success"><a role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#startGrammar" style="color: rgb(255,255,255); text-decoration: none">Start Online Assessment</a></button>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <!-- comment out this part later
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#startCustomer">Start Customer Service Test</a>
                    <br>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button"data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#startLogical">Start Logical Reasoning Test</a>
                    <br>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#startIdioms">Start Idioms Test</a>
                    <br>

                    <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#startCall">Start Call Listening Test</a>
                    -->
                     <button style="margin-left:10px; width: 15%" class= "btn btn-primary"><a role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#viewScores" style="color: rgb(255,255,255); text-decoration: none">View Scores</a></button>
                    <br>
                    <br>

                    <img src="images/border.png" width= "100%" height= "65%">
                    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" id="startGrammar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                <b><p> Instructions:</p></b>
                                    <p>You have 8 minutes to answer all questions. You can only take the test once. Click "Start" if you're ready</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <a href="#GrammarTab" id="gtest" class="btn-sm" role="tab" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="tab" style="color: rgb(91, 55, 119);">Start Grammar Test</a>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

         <!-- need to link the view scores -->
                     <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" id="viewScores" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">View score?</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p>For authorized person only.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#passwordcl">Proceed</button>

                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container">
                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="passwordcl" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Enter password</h4>
                                </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Enter Password here" id="passcl" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">

                                <a href="#ViewScoresTab" id="gtest" class="btn-sm" role="tab" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="tab" style="color: rgb(91, 55, 119);"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onClick="passCheckcl()">Yes</button></a>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**dbinsert.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
//DATABASE CONNECTION HERE
?>
```

Comment: whats shows echo $id in dbinsert.php

Comment: That code should work, so maybe the parameters are not being sent in $_POST or the query is failing

Comment: Also are you submitting any form to index.php which you are doing some test conditions?

Comment: @C0dekid.php I agree its unnecessary, but it will not cause an error.

Comment: Show us all of `index.php:`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Oh really? So using that will not causing any errors? Last time I did, it exploded my script haha. _Oh, wait I see! This is what you can do in PHPmyAdmin either, now I understand :P_

Comment: @C0dekid.php There must have been something else wrong with that query `"SELECT * FROM table;"` works just SuperDuperly. _I just tested it to be sure I was not talking rubbish_

Comment: @Devs it's empty since it doesn't update the data when i use it as the id

Comment: Try removing the `;` at the end of the query...

Comment: @JeroenBellemans see above comment, we have been there already!!

Comment: Yeah, I think so! Maybe the tables or something, but OP needs to check the names from the tables and the query if they match, otherwise the input has characters with `quotes` what will stop the query from executing (SQL Injections)

Comment: Just another thing: is the file where you connect to the db included? As `session_start` needs to be on top, I do not see where the `$conn` variable is coming from...

Comment: Ahh thats better **`session_start() must be run BEFORE any other output is sent to the browser**

Comment: inb4 harsh comment; comment was posted before edit...

Comment: @RiggsFolly the code is quite long now so I only placed those where firstname, etc. can be found

Comment: Oh you also probably spelt `firstname` wrong in the query `fistname`???

Comment: @RiggsFolly so before the '<link rel="stylesheet"...>' stuff?

Comment: See @C0dekid.php answer he has it covered

Comment: Your `<form class="form-horizontal" method="post">` does not actually have an `action="dbinsert.php"` Are you submitting the form via javascript or maybe AJAX. If so show that code also

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the `session_start()` and your database connection on top of your html-code. Remove the PHP code for the connection in your `<head>` and then place it on top of your file.

So it would start like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "offsourcing";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
<html>
....
```

You also misspelled the `fistname`, it should be `firstname`. *See comment below about this misspelling*

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM applicants WHERE lastName='$lname' AND firstName='$fname' AND midName='$mname';");
```

> You may want to look at your input, it's vulnerable to [SQL Injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use `mysqli_real_escape_string` or `prepare()` statement (*recommended*) to escape the input.

Comment: You could add the `firstname` misspelling to your answer as well

Comment: it still doesn't work :/ oh and the fistname is the right name, we wrote it wrong but didn't bother changing yet :p

Comment: Is the `session_start()` the first thing in your real `dbinsert.php` script as well?

Comment: @EymiєlMoralєs Oh ok haha! Does your page show any errors or something? If not, try to place `error_reporting(E_ALL)` on top of your file and tell us what error(s) you got. Also debug your query by placing `or die(mysqli_error($conn));` after your query.

Comment: `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then you will see errors on your browser

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah it's on top of the other php file. But when I update the data in:  $qs = "UPDATE scores SET GrammarScore = $scoregs, GrammarRemark = '$remarkgs' WHERE applicantID = $id"; is it okay to just put $id or should it be $id = $_SESSION['id']?

Comment: You do a `$id = $_SESSION['id']` so you can use `WHERE applicantID = $id` . If the `applicantID` is a text/char column you need to wrap the `$id` in quotes like `WHERE applicantID = '$id'`

Comment: @RiggsFolly so I can assign $id = $_SESSION['id'] at any part of my php script? like for example a php script under the '<body>'?